# Scala Slick-Extensions SQLServerDriver 2.1.0 usage - can't get it to compile

Tags: sql-server, scala, slick

I am trying to use Slick-Extensions to connect to an SQL Server Database from Scala. I use slick 2.1.0 and slick-extensions 2.1.0.

I can't seem to get the code I wrote to compile. I followed the examples from slick's website and this compiled fine when the driver was H2. Please see below:

```
package com.example
import com.typesafe.slick.driver.ms.SQLServerDriver.simple._
import scala.slick.direct.AnnotationMapper.column
import scala.slick.lifted.TableQuery
import scala.slick.model.Table

class DestinationMappingsTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[(Long, Int, Int)](tag, "DestinationMappings_tbl") {
  def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def mltDestinationType = column[Int]("mltDestinationType")
  def mltDestinationId = column[Int]("mltDestinationId")
  def * = (id, mltDestinationType, mltDestinationId)
}
```

I am getting a wide range of errors: scala.slick.model.Table does not take type parameters, column does not take type parameters and O not found. 
If the SQLServerDriver does not use the same syntax as slick, where do I find its documentation?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think to your import of scala.slick.model.Table shadows your import of com.typesafe.slick.driver.ms.SQLServerDriver.simple.Table

Try to just remove the:

```
import scala.slick.model.Table
```